# how to obtain the value of label in edititemplate (of formview) to the code behind file?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, webforms

I'm trying to bring the value of text entered in the label "telephoneidLabel" to my code behind file to set value in the where clause of my sqlcommand object.
how do i do it? 
the edititemtemplate is within the formview.

```
 <EditItemTemplate >   
        telephoneid:
        <asp:Label ID = "telephoneidLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind ("telephoneid")%>' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you catch the correct item you can use the `FindControl` method of the Item, something like this:

```
var myLabel = item.FindControl("telephoneidLabel") as Label;

if(myLabel != null)
{
  var myText = myLabel.Text;
}
```

the way you get the `item` object depends on how your code is, if you do a loop on the whole `formview` control or you get the `editItem` or the `selectedItem` etc... but `FindControl` and its usage is always the same.

Comment: Thanx davide                                                         var telLabel = form1.FindControl("telephoneidLabel") as Label;
       string strtel = telLabel.Text;        it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do - now the two way binding should automatically do this for you, assuming that on the SqlDataSource that you use as the data source for you GridView.  Here's some code I have on the SqlDataSource:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [prov] SET provname=@provname, addr=@addr, tele=@tele WHERE provID=@provID "   >      
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="dgProviders" Name="provID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="login" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="password" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="username" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="contact_email" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="bar_number" />
    </UpdateParameters>
```

Now, if you want to get to the label object, then in an approproate event handler, you can use the following code as an example:

```
Protected Sub dgProviders_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles dgProviders.RowCommand
    Select e.CommandName
        Case "Search"
            Dim strProvName As String = CType(Me.dgProviders.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtSearchName"), TextBox).Text
            If strProvName = String.Empty Then
                Me.lblResults.Text = "<span style=""color:maroon"">You have to enter a search term:  part of the name to do a search.</span><br />"
            Else
                Me.sqlProvList.SelectParameters.Clear()
                If strProvName <> String.Empty Then
                    Me.sqlProvList.SelectCommand = "SELECT provID, provname, addr, tele FROM prov WHERE [provname] LIKE '%' + @username + '%' ORDER BY [provname]"
                    Me.sqlProvList.SelectParameters.Add("username", DbType.String, strProvName)
                End If
                Me.dgProviders.PageIndex = 0
                Session("Select") = Me.sqlProvList.SelectCommand
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

This is from a "search" button that I have, getting values from text boxes in the header row of the data grid.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the row is in edit mode, you should be able to get the value from the control like this:

```
//the row that's being edited
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[0];

if (row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
{
    Label lblCtrl = row.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
    if (lblCtrl != null)
    {
        string text = lblCtrl.Text;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if it might be better to use a datakey for this, though:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="SomeColumn" ...>
```

Code-behind:

```
string someValue = (string)GridView1.DataKeys[0]["SomeColumn"];
```